# ntddk.h file include errors

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to include ntddk.h file in a windows project. When I link to it I get more than 100 errors that go like:

```
3   IntelliSense: cannot open source file "mce.h"   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\km\ntddk.h  100 1   ConsoleApplication1
    2   IntelliSense: cannot open source file "wdm.h"   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\km\ntddk.h  43  1   ConsoleApplication1
    7   IntelliSense: expected a ';'    c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\km\ntddk.h  6279    1   ConsoleApplication1
    9   IntelliSense: expected a ';'    c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\km\ntddk.h  6290    1   ConsoleApplication1
    6   IntelliSense: identifier "_DECL_HAL_KE_IMPORT" is undefined c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\km\ntddk.h  6277    1   ConsoleApplication1
    8   IntelliSense: identifier "_DECL_HAL_KE_IMPORT" is undefined c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\km\ntddk.h  6288    1   ConsoleApplication1
```

Can somebody help me why am I getting all these errors?

Comment: Did you set your include paths properly?

Comment: That is what I am not sure of. I simply did an include<C:\folder\folder\ntddk.h>. If I set up an include path inn project properties that involves the rest of the folder with the other header files from the WinDDK package I get even more errors. Should including this certain header file be enough?

Comment: Additionally I do not get the expected a ';' errors. How can I get semantical errors upon including a windows header file?

Comment: Yeah, you can't include the file with the full path.  You'll need to add the directory it is in to your include paths in the project properties, VC++ Directories page.  The errors are because those missing files have the required `#define xxx` macros to make it work.

Comment: @RetiredNinja you said we can't include the full path. Then what should be the path? Could you please help me out.